# Control the behavior of clicking & Hover on links, buttons and elements on touch screens (with example)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On devices with **touch screens** such as **smartphones and tablets** on some websites, when you **click** on different page elements such as **links, buttons, checkboxes, etc.**, an **effect is displayed** (the background color of the clicked element is an effect Blue fades) which indicates a click on the desired element. But in some websites, **this effect is not displayed** and if any element that can be clicked or hovering, if this is clicked, this effect **will not be displayed** and there will be no change in the background color of the clicked element.

For this topic, I have given two examples. The first is the **stackoverflow site itself**, which by clicking on icons, elements and links, the effect is displayed and the background color of the element changes.

And the **second example** is related to **font pages and Google icons**, which does not happen. Clicking on any element that can be clicked or hovering **does not show any effect** and does not change the background color of that element.
Now my question is **how can this effect be disabled** so that it is not displayed by clicking on any element and this effect does not appear? What is the solution to disable this effect?
**Thankful**

Example number one:

[image]

Example number two :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap color can be disabled by changing the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` to `transparent`

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

[webkit-tap-highlight-color docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color)

Comment: Thanks Dear Friend :)